# How to open a RCP/Help Window from a Html hyperlink in Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Suppose I have a html opened in a Browser. Now in that HTML file , I've a hyperlink and On clicking on that hyperlink, I want to open the Eclipse Help Window.

Same as Like

> Eclipse>Welcome>What's New>Plug-in
>   Development Environment

I know the above is using an intro extension, but I am using a view to display the html. Now please show me a way to achieve the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The welcome screen and a lot of other places where hyperlinks appear in Eclipse UI aren't implemented using Browser widget, but rather using the FormText widget. The FormText widget supports limited markup, including hyperlink rendering. You control behavior of the hyperlink.

This article covers the use of FormText control:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html

It may be possible to achieve what you are after using an actual Browser control, but if your scenario doesn't call for tricky formats, it will definitely be easier using FormText.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll go through the link and try to achieve the desired output